# PostgreSQL: Data Migration Between two databases with different structures using any Integration tool

Tags: postgresql

We redesigned our old project to a new project. we used PostgreSQL as a database in both the projects. The help which I need is, we want to migrate the old project database to a new project database which of different structure(like want to use old database column to new database column with a different name and etc..). I have seen that we can do that using two methods.

1. Dump file ( pg dump -t )
2. Using db link

Do we have any integration tools to that other than the above methods?

Comment: foreign data wrappers and foreign tables

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using an "**Extract Transform Load (ETL)**" or "**Integration**" tool. These tools are easy to learn and use and generally only require a basic knowledge of Structured Query Language (SQL) to get started.

Here's a screenshot of one such tool; SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS):

[image]

There are similar tools available that are open source.

Alternatively - but I wouldn't recommend this - you can generate SQL statements with SQL.

```
SELECT
    'INSERT INTO Target_Table (Field_A, Field_B) VALUES ('
    || Field_1
    || ', '
    || Field_2
    || ');' AS STATEMENT
FROM
    Source_Table
```

Execute on the source database and send the output to a file which is executed on the target database. Here's more information about [How to use SQL to create more SQL](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-sql-to-create-sql/)

Comment: Thank you @rtev. Will go through with this and get back here if I need any help.